# Delete two consecutive constants from a list

Tags: prolog

I have a list and I should to delete consecutive duplicates in the list.

So for example:

```
compress([a,a,b,c,c,d,d,d,e], New_List) 
New_List = [a,b,c,d,e].
```

I have write some code, but when I try I receive false, and don't understand why (I'm a little bit newbie in prolog).

```
compress([],[]).

compress([Head| Rest], New_List):-
    compress(Head, Rest, New_List).

compress([], [], []).

compress(Head, [Head_N | Rest_N], New_List) :-
    Head \== Head_N,
    append([Head], New_List),
    compress(Head_N, Rest_N, New_List).

compress(Head, [Head_N | Rest_N], New_List) :-
    Head == Head_N,
    compress(Head_N, Rest_N, New_List).
```

EDIT 1.

I noticed right now, while i'm writing, that with this code the last letter will never append.

Comment: That's not a predicate, but a constant.

Comment: Sorry my bad google translate.

Comment: `append([Head], New_List)` makes not much sense. `append/3` to append two lists together takes three parameters.

Comment: Mmh, you are right, but to insert element inside a list can I use only append? Because I had thought about adding one item at a time

Comment: no, you can use unification in the head of the predicate as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a helper predicate that drops elements of a list until it finds the next element that is different, or reaches the end of the list:

```
dropEq([], _, []).
dropEq([H|T], X, [H|T]) :-
    dif(H, X).
dropEq([H|T], H, R) :-
    dropEq(T, H, R).
```

next we can use this to compress the list:

```
compress([], []).
compress([H|T], [H|R]) :-
    dropEq(T, H, Q),
    compress(Q, R).
```

Comment: @Jack23: `dif(H, X)` ensures that the values are different. In case the two are variables, it adds a difference constraint, such that if later when the variables are grounded it will fail if the variables eventually are the same.

Comment: @Jack23: the prepending happens, by the `[H|...]` part in `[H|R]` in the second clause of `compress/2`.